# C++ | Why am I getting weird characters after executing this program?

Tags: c++, arrays

After entering some letters to `myString`, I get an output containing exact letters as `myString` with some weird, scrambled up characters.
For example I type in *"letters"* and the output I have is the following:

*letters
 ÷ìu            ╝■( Bñìu¿☻÷u³■( Ê¶ì   Ä◄ÿub◄ÿu←öïÜ            ÉpB º■( ( ─ ( î¯u
Å{N´■   b◄ÿu─[uÉpB ö ( ¯pB ÉpB P4å Ç*

Also this weird characters appear different with different inputs, but they don't change after a rebuild with the same input.

**Here is the code I have wrote:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    constexpr int BUFFER_SIZE = 128;

    char myString[BUFFER_SIZE + 1] = {}; // + 1 for null. Initialize all with null.

    cout << "Enter a string: ";
    fgets(myString, BUFFER_SIZE, stdin);

    int myString_size = sizeof(myString);
    for (int i = 0; i < myString_size; i++) {
        cout << myString[i];
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Now, I know that fgets() function will place an new-line character in the end of *letters* **but why those characters still appear?**

Comment: a simple hint : sizeof is **not** returning the length of the string

Comment: ...and you can't go one-past end anyway.

Comment: So @gogaz what sizeof actually returns is 128, am I right?

Comment: @FeritYiğitBALABAN no sizeof returns the # of bytes for the datatype.

Comment: @gogaz It returns the size of the array, not length of the c-style string. The OP should use `strlen()`rather than `sizeof()` to determine the size of all characters entered.

Comment: I don't know all the fancy stuff you can do with `sizeof` but I'm pretty sure it returns the allocated/needed memory size

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Is it possible to use strlen() function with a char array?

Comment: `strlen` *only* works with `char` arrays.

Comment: `sizeof(myString)` does, indeed, return 128 in this case. But that's not the length of the string, that's the maximum number of `char`'s that `myString` can hold. To get the length of the string, use `strlen(myString)`.

Comment: I fixed: +1 for the buffer size, & initialize it to null. Also I fixed the condition of the for loop. For the matter at hand, see my seperated answer below.

Answer (score 4):

A C string is as long as the number of characters between the beginning of the string and the terminating null character (without including the terminating null character itself). To get the **length** of a C string, use:

```
size_t myString_size = strlen(myString);
```

Than, the loop should looks something like:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < myString_size; i++) {
    cout << myString[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You reserve a buffer `myString` of `128` bytes, which is not initialized in the course of its declaration (i.e. it may contain arbitrary values for each of the 128 bytes). Each of these arbitrary values may yield "something weird" when output to console.

When you enter a string then, e.g. `"Hello!"`, when only the first portion of `myString` will be assigned values, i.e. `H`, `e`, ... , `!`, `\n`, `\0`. All others will remain as they have been before `fgets`, i.e. they still may contain "weird stuff".

In your loop, you print all the `128` characters, i.e. also the weird ones. BTW: with `<=sizeof(myString)`, you go one behind the end of the buffer and access non-reserved memory.

To overcome this, try the following:

```
int main()
{
    char myString[128];
    cout << "Enter a string: ";
    fgets(myString, 128, stdin);
    size_t myString_size = strlen(myString);
    for (size_t i= 0; i < myString_size; i++) {
        cout << myString[i];
    }
}
```

Or:

```
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char myString[128];
    cout << "Enter a string: ";
    fgets(myString, 128, stdin);
    cout << myString;
}
```

Or:

```
int main()
{
    char myString[128];
    cout << "Enter a string: ";
    fgets(myString, 128, stdin);
    size_t myString_size = strlen(myString);
    for (size_t i= 0; i < myString_size && myString[i] != '\0'; i++) {  // stop when reaching the end of the string
        cout << myString[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: I did size_t myString_size = (unsigned)strlen(myString); but now I am getting an error messsage saying : strlen was not declared in this scope. I added string header but why this error?

Comment: Did you `#include <string.h>` (note the `.h`)?

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof(myString)` returns the size of the buffer `char[128]` (in bytes), not the size of the string. To iterate through the characters of the string you can use a loop like this:

```
for (char *c = &myString[0]; *c != '\0' ; ++c)
     std::cout << c;
```

or cast to `std::string`:

```
for (char c : std::string(myString))
     std::cout << c;
```

or more simply:

```
std::cout << std::string(myString);
```